# Is there any triggering policy like SizeAndTimeBasedTriggeringPolicy with FixedWindowRollingPolicy in logback.xml?

Tags: java, log4j, logback, slf4j, spring-logback

In my spring boot project,I am using spring logback.xml. I have a use case in which I have to roll over the file based on file size and date whichever is first and also I need to keep the count of rolled over files to 2 only. I was thinking to use following :

```
<configuration>
 <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  <file>test.log</file>
  <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
   <fileNamePattern>test.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
   <maxIndex>2</maxIndex>
  </rollingPolicy>

  <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
   <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
  </triggeringPolicy>
  <encoder>
   <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
 </appender>

<root level="DEBUG">
<appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

But the above configuration achieves the use case rolling file based on filesize and keeping max count of rolled files to 2. But it does not do the rolling based on date. I need a rolling based on date also, in addition to file size while keeping the number of rolled files to 2. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think below should work. TimeBasedRollingPolicy uses pattern you provide for fileNamePattern which decides whether to append the data to existing file or new one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/logs/${appName}/${HOSTNAME}.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- Rollover every day -->
            <fileNamePattern>/logs/${appName}/${HOSTNAME}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>2</maxHistory>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```